# how to read a .pcm file in java

Tags: java

I am trying to read a .pcm audio file in java, i was using AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream() to read  the file, but i am getting the following error..
javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: could not get audio input stream from input stream..

It is working fine for .wav file....could anyone please help me out with this....